# Signed sums of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let {a$_n$} be a weakly decreasing sequence of positive reals. $\,$ Assume that
the sum $\,$ s = $\sum$ a$_n$ converges. $\,$  Next introduce arbitrary signs $\,$
$\epsilon$$_n$ = +$1$ $\,$ or $\,$ $\epsilon$$_n$ = -$1$ $\,$ and consider the set  $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\quad$ L = { $\sum$ $\epsilon$$_n$a$_n$} $\,$ of all possible signed sums. $\,$  All of these are absolutely convergent and therefore
converge themselves.  Clearly, L is contained in the interval [-s,s] and is 
symmetric about the origin.

For example, if a$_n$ = $\frac{1}{n^2}$ (n $\geq$ 1), then $\,$ s = $\zeta$(2) = 1.644... $\,$ and the resulting set L has the following properties: $\,$
(i) $\,$ L is uncountable.  This is not immediately obvious because even though
the number of sign combinations is uncountable, this is partly balanced out by
a considerable amount of  collapsing.  This comes about from finite coincidences 
such as $\,$ 1/20$^2$ + 1/15$^2$ = 1/12$^2$ $\,$ as well as infinite ones  like 
$\,$ 1/2$^2$ = 1/3$^2$ + 1/4$^2$ + 1/5$^2$ + 1/6$^2$ +1/11$^2$ + $\cdots$ $\,$.
$\,$ However, if you select a thin enough subsequence and change just those signs, then the resulting sums are all distinct $\,$(no collapsing). $\;$ (ii)
$\,$ $0$ $\notin$ L : $\,$  The numerical value $\zeta$(2) = 1 + .644 ... $\,$ shows that the first term of the series always dominates the sum and can't be
cancelled by any combination of the remaining terms. $\,$ (Of course, L also omits an interval around zero). $\,$ (iii) With more work it can be shown that 
L is closed (i.e. contains all its limit points).

So far then, we know only that L is a proper uncountable closed subset of 
[-$\zeta$(2),$\zeta$(2)] , but not what it actually is.

Questions: (1) $\,$  For $\,$ a$_n$ = $\frac{1}{n^2}$ $\,$ as above, $\,$ is it possible to describe the set L explicitly?

(2) $\,$ Let b$_n$ = $\frac{1}{n!}$ $\,$  for n $\geq$ 0 with sum $\sum$
$\frac{1}{n!}$ = e $\,$ and corresponding set $\,$  L $\subset$ [-e,e] .
This L has the same properties as before but is probably sparser due to the
rapid decrease of the b$_n$'s . $\,$ Is there a precise description of the 
set L in this case?

(3) $\,$ Can the series be recovered from the sums?
    $\;$ (a) Are there any other sequences {c$_n$} satisfying $\;$ c$_n$ $\geq$ c$_{n+1}$ > 0  with L({c$_n$}) = L({$\frac{1}{n^2}$}) $\,$? $\;$ (b) $\,$ Is there another sequence $\,$ {d$_n$} $\,$ such that $\;$ L({d$_n$}) = $\;$  L({$\frac{1}{n!}$}) $\,$ ?

Thanks

Comment: [Four months later at mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303799/infinite-series-with-signed-sums)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: apologies for my earlier answer which had an error. Instead of looking at $\sum \epsilon _n a_n$ with $\epsilon_n's \in \{-1,1\}$ we can take                         $\epsilon_n's \in \{0,1\}$ and ask when we  get the entire interval $[0,L]$ where $L=\sum a_n$. These two formulations are equivalent because $c=\pm1$ if and only if $(c+1)/2 =0$ or $1$. Now suppose $a_n >0,\sum a_n <\infty$ and $a_n$ decreases to 0 so fast that $\sum_{N+1}^\infty a_n <a_N$. [This is  the case when $a_n=1/(n!)$]. Then the entire interval   $(\sum_{N+1}^\infty a_n ,a_N)$ can contain no sum of    the type $\sum \epsilon _n a_n$ with $\epsilon_n's \in \{0,1\}$ This fact if obvious since we have to add at least one $a_j$ with $j \leq N$ to increase the left end point of the interval.The series $\sum 1/n^{2}$ does not satisfy the condition $\sum_{N+1}^\infty a_n <a_N$ and I  don't           know the answer for this case.